# Acessing specific table data from table row in React

Tags: reactjs

It is my first time fetching data from an API and I'm quite new to React. Would be greatly appreciated if someone could help!

I am having trouble accessing some data inside a table row. I am trying to access the name property by clicking the row. What I want is to copy the name property from clicking the specific row.

Also, my `useEffect` keeps fetching data non-stop. I've tried to change the dependencies but it keeps doing it no matter what I do. I am passing the endpoint to the API from the button click.

Another thing is that when I am getting the data I would like to access every index of the array members but I tried and couldn't figure it out. So I am only accessing the `index[1]` (`resp.guild.members[1].characters`).

My Code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Tabledata = ({ guildName }) => {
  const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
  const [membersOnline, setMembersOnline] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.tibiadata.com/v2/guild/${guildName}.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
        setMembers(resp.guild.members[1].characters);
        setMembersOnline(() =>
          members.filter((player) => player.status !== "offline")
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [members, guildName]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Enemies Online</h1>
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Vocation</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {membersOnline.map((d, id) => (
            <tr
              key={d.id}
              onClick={(e) => {
                console.log(this.d.name);
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(`exiva "${e.target.value}`);
              }}
            >
              <td>{d.name}</td>
              <td>{d.level}</td>
              <td>{d.vocation}</td>
              <td>{d.status}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabledata;
```

Code working:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Tabledata = ({ guildName }) => {
  // const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
  const [membersOnline, setMembersOnline] = useState([]);
  const [header, setHeader] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.tibiadata.com/v2/guild/${guildName}.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        const members = resp.guild;
        setHeader(resp.guild.data.name);
        const allCharacters = members.reduce((accum, iter) => {
          accum.push(...iter.characters);
          return accum;
        }, []);
        console.log(members);
        console.log(allCharacters);
        setMembersOnline(() =>
          allCharacters.filter((player) => player.status !== "offline")
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [guildName]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>{header}</h1>
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Vocation</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {membersOnline.map((d) => (
            <tr
              key={d.id}
              onClick={(e) => {
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(
                  `exiva "${e.currentTarget.children[0].innerText}`
                );
              }}
            >
              <td>{d.name}</td>
              <td>{d.level}</td>
              <td>{d.vocation}</td>
              <td>{d.status}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabledata;
```

However, if I try to assign resp.guild to members somehow reduce won't work..something like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Tabledata = ({ guildName }) => {
  const [members, setMembers] = useState([]);
  const [membersOnline, setMembersOnline] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.tibiadata.com/v2/guild/${guildName}.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        setMembers(resp.guild);
        setHeader(resp.guild.data.name);
        const allCharacters = members.reduce((accum, iter) => {
          accum.push(...iter.characters);
          return accum;
        }, []);
        setMembersOnline(() =>
          allCharacters.filter((player) => player.status !== "offline")
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [members, guildName]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Enemies Online</h1>
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Vocation</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {membersOnline.map((d, id) => (
            <tr
              key={d.id}
              onClick={(e) => {
                console.log(this.d.name);
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(
                  `exiva "${e.target.value.innerText}`
                );
              }}
            >
              <td>{d.name}</td>
              <td>{d.level}</td>
              <td>{d.vocation}</td>
              <td>{d.status}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabledata;
```

It will throw an exception at reduce saying it is not a function

Answer (score 0):

I have refactored your code, and it is working in a code sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-jennings-x5eki?file=/src/App.js) with no errors in rendering.

I made a few changes after looking at your updated question and looking at the API that you are using.

1. I removed `members` as a state object
2. I am setting the key value of the map function to the index of the array, because `id` is not a property of the `members` in the JSON response body.
3. I removed `members` from the dependency array as it no longer a managed state
4. I removed `setHeader` because it is not defined anywhere in your code example
5. I changed the filter to return offline members because there were literally no members online at the time of writing this.

Please reference the code sandbox I linked in order to fully understand any issues you come across implementing my code.

**As a note:** `navigator.clipboard.writeText()` as you have written it does not work in the code sandbox, but a `console.log` will show the value that is being written to the clipboard is correct.  Questions about clipboard should be asked in their own stack overflow post.

```
const Tabledata = ({ guildName }) => {
  const [membersOnline, setMembersOnline] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`https://api.tibiadata.com/v2/guild/${guildName}.json`)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((resp) => {
        const { members } = resp.guild;
        const allCharacters = members.reduce((accum, iter) => {
          accum.push(...iter.characters);
          return accum;
        }, []);

        setMembersOnline(
          allCharacters.filter(({ status }) => status === "offline")
        );
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, [guildName]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>Enemies Online</h1>
      <table className="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Vocation</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {membersOnline.map((d, i) => (
            <tr
              key={i}
              onClick={(e) => {
                navigator.clipboard.writeText(
                  `exiva ${e.currentTarget.children[0].innerText}`
                );
              }}
            >
              <td>{d.name}</td>
              <td>{d.level}</td>
              <td>{d.vocation}</td>
              <td>{d.status}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tabledata
```